# A question regarding modified binomial summation

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

We know that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\binom {N} {k}a^N b^{N-k} = (a+b)^N
$$
Do we have a formula for the following formula?
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N k\cdot\binom {N} {k}a^{k} b^{N-k}
$$
It looks very similar to compute the mean of a binomial distribution, but $a+b\neq 1$.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the first line: it is:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}a^\color{red}{k} b^{N-k}=(a+b)^N\tag{1} $$
so, by differentiating both sides with respect to $a$, then multiplying them by $a$:
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{N}{k}k a^k b^{N-k} = Na(a+b)^{N-1}.\tag{2}$$